# Initializing a node with some null pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this struct:

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    Node *parent;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node(Node *p, Node *l, Node *r){
        parent = p;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};
```

and then I have the following, where `current` is a `Node*`:

```
current->left = new Node(current, new Node, new Node);
```

But I get

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Node'
 current->left = new Node(current, new Node, new Node);
                                       ^
```

What's the problem? Doesn't `new Node` return a pointer to an uninitialized `Node`, which should satisfy the requirements of the constructor?

Comment: You defined a ctor, so any `Node` should be constructed with that ctor by definition. You cannot have an uninitialized `Node`, this is what ctor are intented for.

Comment: Maybe this will work: `current->left = new Node(current, null, null);` ?

Comment: Avoid using new/malloc, when not needed, in c++/c because you have to delete/free the allocated memory located on the heap.

Comment: @kostek Yes, but `null` should be `NULL`. Also, `nullptr` is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined a constructor for `Node`, it didn't generate the implicit default constructor. By calling `new Node` without any arguments, you are trying to call the default constructor.

> Doesn't `new Node` return a pointer to an uninitialized `Node`?

No. It will construct a new `Node` and return the pointer to it. It probably makes more sense to just pass `nullptr` as the `Node*` arguments.

```
new Node(current, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @RenéG define the constructor you want or pass proper parameters to the constructors you're firing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `struct` doesn't have a constructor which takes no arguments, so it cannot be created with `new Node`. You can create a constructor which takes no arguments, something like `Node() {}`, but the values won't be initialized.